# using a classic asp.net web service in vs2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have an old Webservice (.asmx) created long ago.
I want to use it in a vs2013 c# winforms app.

In the old days, I added a webreference ie "TheService"
and an proxy object was created and added and a just used it myApp.TheService

The old Code:

```
private ADStudent GetStudentWebService()
        {
            AdStudent.ADStudent ws = new AdStudent.ADStudent();
            ws.Url = comboBox_WebServiceUrl.SelectedItem.ToString();
            return ws;
        }
```

In 2013 I added a service reference, but no proxy object was created, so how do I call methods on the service, I can find examples of calling a wcf data service, but not an old school Soap (.asmx) webserivce.

Is there example code anywhere?

Comment: there is no "classic asp.net".  is it classic asp or asp.net?

Comment: Sorry to triggered your parser, I changed the word classic to old school

Comment: Do you mean an .asmx rather than a wcf(.svc) web service? I also don't know what a *classsic asp.net* web service is.

Comment: In that case you can just add the web service following [these instructions on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx). It will generate it in the way it used it, no WCF jiggery pokery

Comment: Perfect! write it up as an answer and I'll mark it correct! Thanks!

Comment: Just a mnior point, while the answer is the same, the questions is very different. Keepign this one might make it easier to those who follow to find the answer they seek.